# pass reference to array in C++

Tags: c++

Can any one help me understand the following code

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(const char * c)
{
   std::cout << "const char *" << std::endl;
}

template <size_t N>
void foo(const char (&t) [N])
{
   std::cout << "array ref" << std::endl;
   std::cout << sizeof(t) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char t[34] = {'1'};
    foo(t);

    char d[34] = {'1'};
    foo(d);
}
```

The output is

```
const char *
array ref
34
```

Why does the first foo calls the `const char *` version ? How can I make it call the reference version ?

Comment: The output is `const char*, const char*` for me on msvc

Comment: The output is as he says, `const char *, array ref, 34` with `gcc-4.3.4` (http://ideone.com/ejyCS).

Comment: Ah, there's nothing like ambiguous overload resolution (aka Koenig lookup). Generally speaking, template functions are chosen last when given more than one choice of function.

Comment: Congratulations, you have come to the very end of C++!

Comment: @Marlon and James: So it's compiler specific? Eeeek!

Comment: @junjanes not quite yet ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618760/c-protected-abstract-virtual-base-pure-virtual-private-destructor

Comment: @Loadmaster: Minor nitpick, but Koenig lookup is a process of determining what functions are to be considered.  Then overload resolution is the following process of determining which one of them to use.  If the code said `::foo(t)`, it would not involve Koenig lookup but would involve overload resolution.

Comment: @junjanes No. @Marlon's compiler is wrong.

Comment: @Alexander: Negative. It's standard-defined.

Comment: @user511274: Time to accept some answers.

Comment: @David: Koenig lookup is not a synonym for overload resolution; it is a very specific rule within overload resolution which is also called Argument-Dependent Lookup. It's not in play here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182838/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-function-that-can-tell-a-fixed-array-from-a-pointer

Answer (score 15):

Conversion of `const char[N]` to `const char*` is considered an "exact match" (to make literals easier, mainly), and between two exact matches a non-template function takes precedence.

You can use `enable_if` and `is_array` to force it to do what you want.

---

A messy way to force it might be:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T* c)
{
   std::cout << "const T*" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
void foo(const T (&t) [N])
{
   std::cout << "array ref" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char t[34] = {'1'};
    foo(t);

    char d[34] = {'1'};
    foo(d);
}

/*
array ref
array ref
*/
```

I realise that the OP had `char` not some generic `T`, but nonetheless this demonstrates that the problem lay in one overload being a template and not the other.

Comment: How do you explain that the second version of `foo()` is called the second time ?

Comment: @otibom: Conversion of `char[N]` doesn't have the same rule. `char[N]` to `const char*` is not an exact match: it's convertible, but the template function matches more easily.

Comment: @otibom The first version ain't const, but the template version takes a const array pointer.

Comment: @otibom: Conversion from `char[34]` to `char*` or to `const char (&) [34]` is "exact match", but conversion from `char[34]` to `const char*` is a pointer conversion, which does make a difference in overloading.

Comment: @aschepler Why is conversion from `char[34]` to `const char (&)[34]` considered an "exact match"? Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @NPS: Because table 12 in the standard says so ("qualification conversions") — find it within 13.3.3.1.4. On the other hand, in `char[34]`->`const char*`, the array-to-pointer conversion is actually "exact match" as well, but you then need a second conversion to get the `const`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I meant why there's no `const` conversion required in `const char (&)[34]` case?

Comment: @NPS: There is, and that's the _only_ conversion that need be performed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "the array-to-pointer conversion is actually "exact match" as well" - Shouldn't an "exact match" need **no** conversions? Maybe I don't understand what an "exact match" is.

Comment: GCC gives an ambiguous overload error for the code in this answer: http://ideone.com/G4spM7

Comment: @interjay: Will investigate tomorrow

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at this modified example with no template.

```
void foo(const char * c)
{
    std::cout << "const char *" << std::endl;
}

void foo(const char (&t) [34])
{
    std::cout << "const char (&) [34]" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char t[34] = {'1'};
    foo(t);
}
```

My compiler says call of overloaded `foo` is ambiguous.  This is because conversions from array to pointer are considered an "Exact" conversion sequence and are not better than the null conversion sequence for overload resolution (Standard section 13.3.3.1.1.)

In the original code, the template parameter `N` can be deduced as 34, but then both non-template `foo(const char*)` and `foo<34>(const char (&)[34])` are considered in overload resolution.  Since neither is better than the other by conversion rules, the non-template function beats the template function.

Fixing things seems tricky.  It seems like the `is_array` template from header `<type_traits>` (from C++0x if possible or Boost if not) might help.

Comment: Indeed, you can use enable_if and is_array to get what you want.

Comment: @Tomalak: Is there a simple way using C++03 and Boost?  I was going to give an example, then realized I absolutely needed rvalue-references, which are not part of the language in the question's tag.

Comment: @aschepler: I updated my answer with an approach involving levelling the playing field.

Comment: @aschepler: (Actually it's about the same as your code above, but from the opposite direction)

Comment: Except my code is for explanation purposes only, not a solution to any problem.  I'm still curious about doing it for only pointer/array to cv-char types.  Maybe `template <typename T> void foo(const T* c, enable_if<is_same<T,char> >* = 0);`?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be different for various compilers.

Mircosoft and Borland both use the const char* version, while GNU is giving the output you described.

Here is a snippet from the C++ standard:

> 14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call
>   [temp.deduct.call]
>
> Template argument deduction is done by
>   comparing each function template
>   parameter type (call it P) with the
>   type of the corresponding argument of
>   the call (call it A) as described
>   below.
>
> If P is not a reference type:
>
> -- If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer 
>   standard conversion (4.2) is used in
>   place of A for type deduction;
>   otherwise,
>
> -- If A is a function type, the pointer type produced by the
>   function-to-pointer     standard
>   conversion (4.3) is used in place of A
>   for type deduction; otherwise,
>
> -- If A is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of A's type
>   are     ignored for type deduction.
>
> If P is a cv-qualified type, the top
>   level cv-qualifiers of P's type are
>   ignored for type deduction. If P is a
>   reference type, the type referred to
>   by P is used for type deduction

The compiler will build an `A` list as follows:

```
Argument:        t                 d
A:          char const[34]      char[34]
```

And parameter list `P`:

```
Parameter:       c                 t
P:            char const*       char const& t[N]
```

By default the compiler should choose non-referenced parameters. GNU is dong it wrong the second time for some reason.

Comment: No, it is not. You're forgetting about non-templates being preferred. If MS and Borland give different output, then they are non-compliant. Template type deduction is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Template deduction argument is not the issue.  Overload resolution is.