# Explicit decay of an array into a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11

**What is the most concise and idiomatic way of *explicitly* decaying an array into a pointer?**

---

For example, consider the case where you need to be able to guide SFINAE or be explicit about an overload:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> void foo(T(&x)[N]);
template<typename T>                void foo(T *x); 
//
int x[2] = {0, 1};
foo(x);
```

Comment: With a unary plus maybe?

Comment: What are you asking? The code above is not ambiguous.

Comment: @juanchopanza Have you tried it? I agree it's weird, but both are Exact Matches.

Comment: @dyp I tried it. The first one is a better match. Or is my compiler (gcc 4.7.3) broken?

Comment: coliru's clang++ and g++ both say it's ambiguous: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/078c26aeb1abb226

Comment: Yes, they are ambiguous. I never got around to looking more into it, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5173628/560648)

Comment: Another option would be explicit template selection...

Comment: You can avoid the ambiguity by defining the second template as `template<typename T>  void foo(T * const& x);`. No array decay will happen anymore during argument deduction for `T`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb A final standard way has been introduced in C++14 : `std::decay` , see my last update

Comment: *Related:* [What is the purpose of unary plus operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25701381/183120) and [what is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/183120).

Answer (score 9):

You may use one of the following:

```
foo(x + 0);
foo(+x);
foo(&x[0]); // assuming operator& has not been overloaded for T
foo(std::addressof(x[0])); // since C++11
```

Comment: The center one (as has `&*x`, but not `&x[0]`) has the unique advantage that the array element type doesn't have to be complete, so it works on `struct Foo { static ForwardDeclaredType array[]; };`

Comment: I like `+x` the best. It’s a convenient way to say “do the usual conversions & promotions”, for example if you want to send a `uint8_t` to an `ostream` as a formatted integer instead of a raw byte.

Answer (score 5):

The most concise and idiomatic ? I would say taking the address of the first element

```
foo(&x[0]);
```

### UPDATE

Since c++11 there's a [standard way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) of saying the above:

```
auto a = std::addressof(x[0]); // a will be * to int
```

`adressof` has the following signature

```
template<class T> T* addressof(T& arg);
```

and Obtains the actual address of the object or function arg, **even in presence of overloaded operator&**

Another idea (which also has the advantage of the above) would be to write

```
auto a = std::begin(x); // a will be * to int
```

additionally this works with arrays of incomplete types because it requires no application of `[0]`

### UPDATE 2

**Since c++ 14** there's even more explicit functionality on this : [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

Comment: @Deduplicator Then you could use `+x` as well. Is that more readable? Easier to understand?

Comment: @dyp: THe question wanted `concise and idiomatic`. It's no less readable, harder to understand or less idiomatic. Still, not much better than +0 (it has more binding power though). Less concise than unary plus...

Comment: @Deduplicator For an array I think `&x[0]` is easier to read, and can be extended to apply to any class that provides an `operator[]` method (and if it doesn't supply an `operator*`, then `&*c` won't work.  Perhaps on a `std:vector`, or `std:array`?).  If you say `&*c`, I'm thinking that `c` is an iterator of some sort, or some sort of proxy object and I'm trying to get the address of the actual object.

Comment: It looks quite good, just for the last one (std::begin) you still have to add `&*`, because it yields an iterator (which need not be a pointer). But just as you argue that there are some containers not providing `operator*`, there are some smart-pointers not providing `operator[]`. So, `&*p` and `&p[0]` are of equal worth, I personally preferring the first.

Answer (score 2):

The stock `&x[0]` always felt awkward to me because the array in question can be an array of incomplete types, and it is of course invalid to apply a subscript operator to one. Consider this instead,

```
foo(&*x);
```

this is only one more characters to type than `foo(+x)` which is far less readable and harder to grok.

Comment: To clarify, `[0]` can be used on an incomplete array type (whose elements are complete types); but not on an array of incomplete types.

Comment: Additionally, if one works with zero array length *extensions*, traversing through `x[0]` to obtain the address is notionally wrong.

Comment: I've seen long debates about whether `&x[0]` and `x+0` are equivalent in C++ (they are in C) for array types; some feel that `&x[N]` should be undefined if `N` is the length.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Agree, if one argues that `&x[N]` is undefined for some values of `N` why go there at all and start to distinguish between valid and invalid lengths, instead of just doing `&*x` working with `x` the type itself directly.

Comment: @mockinterface What if `x` is an array of types that overload the `&` operator ? You can check my answer for two solutions on this

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou Thanks for your effort Nikos, but I think you rather contradict yourself - your real answer employs '&' so it is subject to the same problem of overloading (and overloading address-of is rather far-fetched and very rare), and while I appreciate that you mentioned the standard ways - they are not concise, and I think that `&*x` is better than `&x[0]` for the reasons I gave in my answer.