# Can not pass 1D array in std::thread

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, c++11

This is for my actual project, but I made a minimal example (code is based on an example of Lightness Races in Orbit).

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    Foo(int n = 10)
    {
        size_t a[n];
        constexpr int p = 5;
        std::thread threads[p];
        for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
            threads[i] = std::thread(std::bind(&Foo::bar, this, a, n));

        for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
    }

    void bar(size_t* a, int n) {}
};

int main() {std::cout << "ok\n";}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1162f9fbcb6a48b8)</kbd>**

The error comes by the fact that I am using an array that has `n` as its size. However, it will be very difficult for me -in the real project- to change that, since many lines of code are based on that.

Comment: How about using a vector?

Comment: Have you tried passing `&a[0]`?

Comment: Hopefully, you learned your lesson about using variable-length arrays in C++...

Comment: How about doing explicit dynamic allocation with the new operator instead of using the variable-length array... those things always have acted funny for me.

Comment: @RubixRechvin I think you mean "how about using vector" :P

Comment: @juanchopanza that did the trick! Are you going to answer the question or should I delete it? Well, I have to admit that this was a fair warning guys!

Comment: @Borgleader That'll work too :) Vectors are pretty and oh so fun to use. If you're into all that kind of stuff ;)

Comment: [`std::thread::join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) has a precondition that the thread is *joinable*. In your program `threads[p - 1]` is not joinable - since you only initialize `p - 1` elements in the first loop - so calling `join` on that thread in the second loop has undefined behavior.

Comment: Nice catch @Casey, I'll call it a typo I made when making this minimal example. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a vector

Or solve the problem by decaying the array into a pointer *before* type deduction takes place:

```
std::bind(&Foo::bar, this, +a, n)
```

The problem is, bind is deducing an array reference and then tries to copy it /by value/. Array copy is not specified by the language.

Comment: Nice trick! BTW "use a vector" would have different semantics, because the thread would have its own copy. Worth pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you sehe, I am trying to make the concepts you and another user introduced to me in another post if you remember. :) However, what about `&a[0]`? It works too. Which one should I prefer? I also do not understand what we did in your answer, `+a` is something new to me.

Comment: @G.Samaras The unary operator `+` applied to the array makes it decay to a pointer. See [this example](http://ideone.com/Beekw1). It is a nice trick, but I would probably do something more explicit (such as `&a[0]`).

Comment: @G.Samaras Applying unary `+` causes the array to [decay into a pointer to the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25701381/241631). If I had to use a C-style array, I'd use `&a[0]` because the former would confuse a lot of people. Also, I don't see why you need `bind` at all to solve your problem, passing those argument to the `thread` constructor should be sufficient.

Comment: You are right Praetorian, `bind` is redundant. Thanks, I will use `&a[0]` for readability. Thanks for the example juanchopanza, really straightforward.

Comment: @G.Samaras I'd use `std::array<size_t, n>::data()`

Comment: Yes that would be a solution too I guess. :)