# char to hex with the same byte size C++

Tags: c++

```
int main () {
  char k = 0xd8;
  cout << hex << k << endl;
}
```

For some reason this prints out the character form of `k` and not the hex form of `d8`. Doing `cout << hex << (int) k << endl;` gives me `ffffd8` which is not the one I want.

Comment: It looks like you meant for `k` to have type `unsigned char`; `char` may be signed and thus has no guarantee of being able to store a number as large as `0xd8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply one of the many deficiencies in `C++`, and another reason why I stick with `C` when I can. You can read more about the topic in the references I provided below. To save yourself some hassle, consider just going with the `printf()` family of functions in production code, as the fix isn't guaranteed to be standards-compliant.

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char k = 0xd8;
    cout << "k = 0x" << hex << +k << endl;
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
k = 0xd8
```

**References**

---

1. Code critique: Stack Overflow posters can’t print the numeric value of a char, [`http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/08/code-critique-stack-overflow-posters-cant-print-the-numeric-value-of-a-char/`](http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/08/code-critique-stack-overflow-posters-cant-print-the-numeric-value-of-a-char/), *Explicit C++*, Accessed 2015-09-27
2. Tippet: Printing numeric values for chars (and (u)int8_t), [`http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/tippet-printing-numeric-values-for-chars-and-uint8_t/`](http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/tippet-printing-numeric-values-for-chars-and-uint8_t/), *Explicit C++*, Accessed 2015-09-27

Comment: Aside: `+k` is essentially just an esoteric way of writing `(int) k`. (or maybe `(unsigned int) k`; I don't recall that detail)

Comment: Also, what exactly about this do you believe isn't standards compliant?  There are good reasons for using `printf` in C++, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25701418/103167