# Same program behavior is different in g++ & MSVS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, g++, virtual-destructor

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618760/c-protected-abstract-virtual-base-pure-virtual-private-destructor). The accepted answer of the linked question contains following code:

```
class Base
 {
    private:
        virtual ~Base() = 0;   /* A */
 };

 class Derived : protected virtual Base
 {
    private:
     ~Derived () {.......}    /* B */
 };
```

I tried this program in g++ 4.8.1, 4.9.2 & MSVS 2010 compiler (see live demo [here.](http://ideone.com/pGUgzR)). But g++ 4.8.1 & 4.9.2 gives me an compiler error while MSVS 2010 compile it without any error.
Clang also gives an error see [here](https://goo.gl/RWRtB1).

So, why g++ shows error message? I haven't created an object of derived class. So, I think it shouldn't give compilation error & MSVS 2010 is correct.

But why both this compiler behaves differently?

Which compiler is right regarding behavior of this program? Is this bug in any of these compilers or something other?

I am indeed getting confused.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Who voted to close? give the reason why you voted to close?

Comment: I think this is a good question.

Comment: Presumably just differences in how the compilers handle unused code at various stages of the compiling process.  Note that in VS2015 there's a highlighted error in the editor saying it's inaccessible before you even attempt to compile it.

Comment: Who downvoted it? Why? Give the reason for downvote.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Still not get any useful answer. Why so much delay to answer this question.?

Comment: @Downvoters: dare to write the reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that g++ and clang (and VS2012) are correct.  And that VS2010 is incorrect.

Essentially, to destruct an instance of `Derived`, the compiler must determine if the destructor of `Base` is accessible.   A `private` destructor of a base class is not accessible to the derived class, so `Derived` cannot be destructed.

I would suggest this does not require that the class be instantiated.   Under the "separate compilation" model, a compiler must assume that some other compilation unit (invisible to the compiler when compiling *this* compilation unit) will instantiate and/or destroy an instance of the class.   Which means it should check/compile/emit code for the destructor in every compilation unit which has visibility of the definition of that destructor.

Rules related to the "separate compilation" model are among those known informally as "as if" rules - an implementation must act *as if* it follows each rule, even if it does things differently under the hood.

The thing is, the various "as if" rules are where compiler vendors often take shortcuts - in the interests of speed of compilation, or other things.

This is only one possible explanation of why VS2010 is getting it wrong.

The upshot is that VS2010 is not properly checking accessibility of destructors in such cases.   Older Microsoft C++ compilers were quite notorious for being less than fully standard compliant.  In recent years, Microsoft has strategically sought to improve their conformance with the standard, but it takes time for such things to flush out.    This would be consistent with the observation that VS2010 does not complain, but VS2012 (like other compilers) does.

One possible explanation of this is that VS2010 does not fully comply with requirements of "separate compilation".   Another is that is simply takes shortcuts when checking accessibility of private members in base classes.   To determine if either of these - or something else - is the explanation, it would probably be necessary to dig into details of how VS2010 is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like this compiles in VS2010 just because the class 'Derived' is never used. I tried the same in VS2012. If you're going to use that class in VS2012 compilation fails as well:

```
class Base
{
    virtual ~Base()=0;      /* A */
};
Base::~Base() { }

class Derived : protected virtual Base
{
  ~Derived()                    /* B */
  { }
};

int main() 
{
  Derived derived;
}
```

Error Message was:

```
1>c:\repositories\teststrongvirtualdestructor\teststrongvirtualdestructor\teststrongvirtualdestructor.cpp(20): error C2248: 'Derived::__vbaseDtor' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Derived'
1>          c:\repositories\teststrongvirtualdestructor\teststrongvirtualdestructor\teststrongvirtualdestructor.cpp(14) : compiler has generated 'Derived::__vbaseDtor' here
1>          c:\repositories\teststrongvirtualdestructor\teststrongvirtualdestructor\teststrongvirtualdestructor.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'Derived'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: You've created object of Derived. That's why it fails in compilation because derived destructor is private. Have you tried this program keeping main() function empty in VS 2012 or later?

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried first. Compilation works in that case. I only made use of that class because I was quite sure that it only compiles because it's not used and so VS compiler doesn't care.

Comment: Looks like the question is not yet ansered for you. Anser is: The code has an error which happily compiles in Visual Studio because the errorneous code is not used. GCC does some extra error checking and therefore can tell you about that error.

Answer (score -2):

If the base destructor is private, it won't be able to delete inherited instances. Simple as that. This isn't standardized, however.